# Target WSGI scriptcannot be loaded as Python module

Tags: django, python-3.x, windows, apache

I am looking for some help in migrating a web app from local machine to apache server.

-Python 3.7
-Django 2.1
-Apache 2.4

I also have a virtualenvironment created for the FleetManagRApp. My httpd.conf looks like this.

```
LoadFile "c:/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python36"

Listen 9981
<VirtualHost *:9981>
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/WebApps/wsgi.py"
Alias /static "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/FCApp/static"
<Directory "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/FCApp/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/WebApps">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 3456
<VirtualHost *:3456>
path="E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/"
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py"
Alias /static "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/PMApproval/static"
<Directory "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/PMApproval/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

wsgi.py looks like below

```
import os
import sys
path = 'E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp'  # use your own username here
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'FleetManagRApp.settings')

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Error Log

```
 mod_wsgi (pid=21464): Target WSGI script 'E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module.
 mod_wsgi (pid=21464): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py'.
Traceback (most recent call last):\r
  File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\utils.py", line 115, in load_backend\r
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)\r
  File "c:\\python36\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\r
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 941, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load\r
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sql_server'\r
\r
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:\r
\r
Traceback (most recent call last):\r
  File "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>\r
    application = get_wsgi_application()\r
  File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application\r
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r
  File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 27, in setup\r
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\registry.py", line 108, in populate\r
     app_config.import_models()\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\config.py", line 202, in import_models\r
     self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\importlib\\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module\r
     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)\r
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import\r
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load\r
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked\r
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked\r
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module\r
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\r
   File "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp\\PMApproval\\models.py", line 6, in <module>\r
     class ApprovalLog(models.Model):\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py", line 124, in __new__\r
     new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\base.py", line 330, in add_to_class\r
     value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\models\\options.py", line 214, in contribute_to_class\r
     self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__\r
     return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\utils.py", line 211, in __getitem__\r
     backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])\r
   File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\db\\utils.py", line 134, in load_backend\r
     raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)\r
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'sql_server.pyodbc' isn't an available database backend.\r
 Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:\r
     'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql', 'sqlite3'\r
 Error was: No module named 'sql_server'\r
 mod_wsgi (pid=21464): Target WSGI script 'E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
 mod_wsgi (pid=21464): Exception occurred processing WSGI script 'E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py'., referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
Traceback (most recent call last):\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
  File "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py", line 19, in <module>\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
    application = get_wsgi_application()\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
  File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\core\\wsgi.py", line 13, in get_wsgi_application\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
    django.setup(set_prefix=False)\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
  File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\__init__.py", line 27, in setup\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
  File "c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\django\\apps\\registry.py", line 78, in populate\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
    raise RuntimeError("populate() isn't reentrant")\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
RuntimeError: populate() isn't reentrant\r, referer: http://localhost:3456/approve
```

The first app is not managed by virtual environment (uses python 3.6 and django 1.7) and I cant control that. I am unable to point my app to the virtual env. I am by no means a web developer. Just one of the enthusiastic tool builders. How can I point my app to the venv without touching the first app ?

Comment: this is a complete guide on how you can deploy a django app into ubuntu and how you can point apache to your virtualenv https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-django-web-framework-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution.

Here are steps:

- Abandoned the venv that comes with Python
- Create a new virtual environment using virtualwrapper-win in the server
- pip install mod_wsgi
- run mod_wsgi to get the path for httpd.conf

```
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/username/envs/venv/lib/sitepackages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd")
```

- modify wsgi.py

  - point and activate virtual environment

Files Below:

```
wsgi.py
activate_this = 'c:/users/username/envs/venv/Scripts/activate_this.py'
# execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
exec(open(activate_this).read(),dict(__file__=activate_this))
import os
import sys
import site
# Add the site-packages of the chosen virtualenv to work with
site.addsitedir('c:/users/username/envs/venv/lib/site-packages/')
# Add the app's directory to the PYTHONPATH
sys.path.append('E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp')
sys.path.append('E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp')
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'FleetManagRApp.settings'
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "FleetManagRApp.settings")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

and the httpd.conf looks like:

```
LoadFile "c:/python36/python36.dll"
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/python36/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "c:/python36"
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/WebApps/wsgi.py"
WSGIPythonPath "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/FCApp/"
Listen 9981
<VirtualHost *:9981>

Alias /static "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/FCApp/static"
<Directory "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/FCApp/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>


<Directory "E:/DjangoSite/WebApps/WebApps">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Listen 3456
<VirtualHost *:3456>
LoadModule wsgi_module "c:/users/username/envs/venv/lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi.cp36-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIScriptAlias / "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp/wsgi.py"
Alias /static "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/PMApproval/static"
<Directory "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/PMApproval/static">
Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory "E:/FleetManagRDjango/FleetManagRApp/FleetManagRApp">
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If this is going to production, you don't necessarily need a virtual environment, but if you do, venv should work fine. You can look at the template here https://github.com/Johnnyboycurtis/webproject/blob/master/httpd.conf.template